# Reading a specific number of lines of a .csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I am trying to read into python and then I want to store the first two columns in a variable called name and gender.  The current code I am using is the following:

```
import csv
infile = open('blue.csv', 'r')
csvfile = csv.reader(infile)

name = []
gender = []

for row in csvfile:
    name.append(row[0])
    gender.append(row[1])
```

There are two problems I am encountering:

1) The csv file has headers so I don't want those included inside the variables when I store the columns

2) I am missing the gender for the last row of the csv file and so I don't want to include the last line of the csv file when I store it in a variable.

I am an `R` programmer and so to me, the way I would get around this is to read in the file excluding the first row and last row but I am unsure of how to do this in python, or better yet, if there is a better/smarter alternative.

If it helps, here is what a mock dataset would look like:

```
Name, Gender
Bob, Male
Susan, Female
Doug,
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your csv ?

Comment: I did, its above in the mock dataset.

Comment: The mock data set is not my python code.

Comment: If you have a privilege to use pandas, please have a look: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote

> I am an R programmer and so to me, the way I would get around this is to read in the file excluding the first row and last row but I am unsure of how to do this in python

This can be done with [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) like so:

```
open('foo.csv').readlines()[1: -1]
```

Furthermore, note that [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) takes both a file object and a list:

> csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.

So you can just use:

```
for l in csv.reader(open('foo.csv').readlines()[1: -1]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are an R programmer, I would recommend you to try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

1) The csv file has headers so I don't want those included inside the variables when I store the columns

You can read csv [read_csv()](http://file%20using%20http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which takes care of headers without any setting.

2) I am missing the gender for the last row of the csv file and so I don't want to include the last line of the csv file when I store it in a variable.

I think your requirement is to skip the lines with missing data, you can use [dropna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

So, coding part:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: !cat sample_data.csv
Name, Gender
Bob, Male
Susan, Female
Doug,

In [3]: pd.read_csv("./sample_data.csv").dropna()
Out[3]: 
    Name   Gender
0    Bob     Male
1  Susan   Female
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing in combination with a try except loop as so:

```
for row in csvfile[1:]:
    try:
        gender.append(row[1])
        name.append(row[0])
    except:
        continue
```

This code skips over any line that doesn't have a gender, not only the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f1:
    numberOflines = len([line for line in f1]) -2
    f1.seek(0)
    r = csv.reader(f1)
    next(r, None) # skip first line
    for row in r:
        if numberOflines > 0:
            print(row[0])
            numberOflines -=1
```